# Как передать параметры из страницы в плагин для обработки в Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Нужно результаты форм отправлять в плагин для обработки.

Пока вижу только вариант с шорткодом.

Например, на нужной странице подключаю шорткод и передаю в него массив полей формы с их значением:

```
$array = [
    "title" => "title",
    "description" => "description"
];
    
$json = json_encode($array);
do_shortcode( sprintf( '[test_shortcode ids="%s"]', $json ) );
```

В плагине это получаю следующим образом:

```
add_shortcode('test_shortcode','my_shortcode_output');

function my_shortcode_output($atts, $content = '', $tag){
    echo $atts[0];
}
```

Результат:

```
ids="{"title":"title","description":"description"}"
```

Далее нужно парсить. Как-то выглядит не очень красиво все это. Может, есть более элегантный способ в Вордпрессе для подобных задач?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для нужного Вам функционала, в WordPress есть отличное понятие как хуки ([hooks](https://wp-kama.ru/id_6680/kak-rabotayut-huki.html)). Пример для вашего кода будет выглядеть следующим образом.

В плагине в том месте, где нужно вызвать(вывести) функцию из темы инициализируем хук:

```php
do_action( 'plugin_custom_hook' );
```

В файле темы

```php
add_action( 'plugin_custom_hook', 'ex_function' );
function ex_function() {
    echo 'test';
    echo 'description';
}
```